# Adding jars in build path shows project error

Tags: android, eclipse, jackson, android-library

I added the jackson jars files in the projects libs folder it didn't worked. And I added them to lib folder and added to build path. The source code worked but still showing some red ! mark on the project on Android project.

Does anyone have ever been in the situation?  How to fix it?

[image]

The second screenshot of the project. They are all in, but still what's going wrong?

[image]

Tried this one too .. but no luck.

[image]

Comment: is jackson a library project like google play services library project?

Comment: not exactly .. I have downloaded the jars separately.

Comment: right click on your project. Goto properties. java build path . order export tab. check if android private libraries is checked. This is just a suggestion

Comment: @Raghunandan please see my second screenshot.

Comment: check Android 4.2.2 check all the jars. cleacn and build

Comment: check all the jars also then clean and build

Comment: no luck again :( .. i am stuck here ..

Comment: In Eclipse, go to the "Problems" perspective and post what it says. You haven't given us any indication of what the error actually is, you've only said that the red ! appears. Here's a screenshot of what I mean: [The problems perspective](http://i.imgur.com/i1vJqpl.png)

Comment: I think I got it solved when I changed the jars files .. may be the corrupted jars of jackson 2.2.1. The project started working after changing the jars from jackson 2.2.2. Anyways thanks to all.